# How to read/execute NSIS script from memory in VB program

Tags: vb.net, nsis

I have a VB.NET application that is essentially a front end for a NSIS script.  The script is called with all of the files and variables given on the commandline.  The purpose of the application is to search and find these files on a persons computer, then format the commandline and call the NSIS script to create the installer.

I want to be able to distribute this program and protect NSIS script source code.  What I was looking for is a way to "read" the script from memory within the application.  My idea is that the contents of the script would be saved inside of the application, then whenever it is needed the script could be loaded and called without ever having to actually write it to the users computer.

Is this possible?  If so what should I look for to accomplish it.  I don't need step by step (not that you could provide one with such a skeletal outline) just what is the major concept or functions inside VB that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the official NSIS compiler and not a custom .dll version? If that is the case then someone can just replace `makensis.exe` with something that writes `stdin` to a file. NSIS 3 also supports dumping the preprocessed script to `stdout` or a file so if you allow your users to modify the switches passed to `makensis` then this would be a easy way to recover most of your script.

Even if we take NSIS out of the equation you are stuck with a problem that is hard to solve. I would suggest that you just encrypt the script with a simple XOR cipher, this should stop most people just looking at your .exe in a hex-editor. You can of course use [stronger encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx) if you want.

When you are about to call `makensis` you would [retrieve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader.aspx) the encrypted script resource as a memory stream or array, decrypt it and then pass it as the `stdin` for `makensis` by using [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckefhahx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: I haven't made through the part of redirecting standard input yet, but I found an example for the XOR cipher code [link](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5676)

Comment: I marked this as answered but i was never fully able to get it to work.  Whenever reading the NSIS script I received an error that I couldn't resolve.  Instead of getting stuck on this I used the XOR function and copied the deXORed file to a temp folder, read the script from there then deleted the temp folder.